# Save canvas data in ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, canvas

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
      var canvas = document.getElementById("uploader-box"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
      video = document.getElementById("video"),
      videoObj = { "video": true },
      errBack = function(error) {
        console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code); 
      };
  ); 
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");    
  dataURL = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");    
  $('#some_text_area_id').val(dataURL); // set the response in text area    
//      jQuery('#web_image').value(image);
       jQuery.ajax({
      url: "/my_controller/myaction",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: 'image_data='+dataURL,
      cache: false,
      beforeSend:function(){

      },
      success: function (response_data) {

      },
      error: function(response_data) {
      }

   });
```

**In controller file i have written**

```
data = params[:image_data]
file_obj=File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/images/test.png","wb") do |file|
  file.write(Base64.decode64(params[:image_data]))
```

It gives

```
Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - test.png):
```

This error please some one help me. If any another way to save canvas data in ruby please tell me

Thanks,

Comment: The error "Permission denied - test.png" sounds like your code is trying to save the file, but your directory isn't allowing you to write into it. Check the permissions for the destination directory.

Comment: drwxrwxrwx permission of images folder and i want to save this in images folder

Comment: What is your current-working directory when you try to save the file? Use `puts Dir.pwd` to find out. I suspect it isn't what you think it is. The best practice is to use the full path for the file, including the absolute path, rather than rely on assumed defaults.

Comment: +1 Thanks for that regex in the data string, that was exactly what I needed :)